# How to align bootstrap image center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Align image center. I am using 3.3.7 version of bootstrap. I tried used text-center or style="text-align:center" did not work for me

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="overflow:hidden" class="col-sm-8">
        <img src="../../../../Images/ThinkstockPhotos-457383369.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to center the image? Into the `col` or into the `row` ?

Comment: I want center of row

Answer (score 1):

Add '`center-block`' to image as class - no additional css needed

```
<img src="images/default.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: I tried center block i dont know why its not working

Comment: No error not aligning on center..no error in console

Comment: @user1030181 `center-block` should work, not then try my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if looking for inline css solution. add margin:0 auto.

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto;" class="col-sm-8">
        <img src="../../../../Images/ThinkstockPhotos-457383369.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap has a class that centers: `.pagination-centered`

It worked for me to do:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 pagination-centered"><img src="header.png" alt="header" /></div>
</div>
```

The css for the class is:

```
.pagination-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I want fit big image inside div